# Creating security rule depend on doc data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I just added new value to my users collection appVersion

My user collection like:

documents/users/5kwgNgGi3sY6oCbUAg9v

[image]

so i just added value versionCode to collection. if user download new app it will be update
My rule now:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth !=null
    }
  }
}
```

what i need as a if else statement

```js
if(request.auth!=null){
firebase().collection('users').where('UID','==',request.auth.uid).get().then(x=>{
    if(x.docs[0].versionCode==4){
      allow
    }
    else{
      deny
    }})
else{
  deny
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to perform a query in your security rules, as that would never scale on the backend.

Instead, what you'll want to do is store the user documents with the UID as the document ID, so that the document you show is at path `documents/users/xHzKoXbrZqbHZY8DI3wkXnMShF92`. Then you can use `get()` in your rules to load the document, as shown in the documentation on [accesing other documents in your rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

I'd also recommend checking out the documentation on [attribute-based and Role-based access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access), as it covers a pretty similar scenario.

Comment: thank you. i changed all docs id with UID parameter.